# How to use mysql query multiple times

Tags: php, mysql

I have this select menu in a for loop, so the query is running multiple times. And a lot of more of these queries so page loads very slow.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <label for="edit_kwaliteit_id['.$i.']">Kwaliteit</label>
    <div class="form-group input-group has-success has-feedback" id="edit_kwaliteit_id_div['.$i.']">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span style="display: inline-block; width:15px; text-align:center;" class="fab fa-squarespace" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>

          <select class="form-control" id="edit_kwaliteit_id['.$i.']" name="edit_kwaliteit_id" onchange="validate_edit_table_1(this, '.$i.')">';

              $sql_kwal = "SELECT
                            id,
                            kwaliteit
                            FROM kwaliteit
                            ORDER BY kwaliteit ASC
                            ";

                if(!$res_kwal = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql_kwal)) { echo '<div class="alert alert-danger text-center" role="alert">Er is helaas iets fout gegaan.</div>'; }

                while($row_kwal = mysqli_fetch_array($res_kwal)) {

                    echo '<option ';if($row_table_1['kwaliteit_id'] == $row_kwal['id']) { echo 'selected="selected"';} echo 'value="'.$row_kwal['id'].'">'.$row_kwal['kwaliteit'].'</option>';
                }
                echo '
          </select>

        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" id="edit_kwaliteit_id_glyp['.$i.']"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Since the query is the same everytime I wanted to move the query out of the loop and place the query itself before the loop.
Something like

```
<?php
// some code
$sql_kwal = "SELECT
            id,
            kwaliteit
            FROM kwaliteit
            ORDER BY kwaliteit ASC
            ";

if(!$res_kwal = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql_kwal)) { echo '<div class="alert alert-danger text-center" role="alert">Er is helaas iets fout gegaan.</div>'; }

// start loop

<div class="col-md-4">
    <label for="edit_kwaliteit_id['.$i.']">Kwaliteit</label>
    <div class="form-group input-group has-success has-feedback" id="edit_kwaliteit_id_div['.$i.']">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span style="display: inline-block; width:15px; text-align:center;" class="fab fa-squarespace" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>

          <select class="form-control" id="edit_kwaliteit_id['.$i.']" name="edit_kwaliteit_id" onchange="validate_edit_table_1(this, '.$i.')">';

                while($row_kwal = mysqli_fetch_array($res_kwal)) {

                    echo '<option ';if($row_table_1['kwaliteit_id'] == $row_kwal['id']) { echo 'selected="selected"';} echo 'value="'.$row_kwal['id'].'">'.$row_kwal['kwaliteit'].'</option>';
                }
                echo '
          </select>

        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" id="edit_kwaliteit_id_glyp['.$i.']"></span>
    </div>
</div>

// end loop
?>
```

But now `while($row_kwal = mysqli_fetch_array($res_kwal))` gives an empty result. Any suggestions to keep one query instead of an query in each loop?

Comment: Could be a scope issue. Try changing `if(!$res_kwal = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql_kwal)) {...` to `$res_kwal = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql_kwal); if (!$res_kwal) {...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read all the rows into an array when you first run the query, and then iterate that array in your `for` loop e.g.

```
$sql_kwal = "SELECT
            id,
            kwaliteit
            FROM kwaliteit
            ORDER BY kwaliteit ASC
            ";

if(!$res_kwal = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql_kwal)) { echo '<div class="alert alert-danger text-center" role="alert">Er is helaas iets fout gegaan.</div>'; }
$rows = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res_kwal)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

Then in your loop, replace

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res_kwal)) {
```

with

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
```

Note that if you have the MySQL native driver (`mysqlnd`) installed, you can use

```
$rows = mysqli_fetch_all(MYSQLI_BOTH);
```

in place of the `while` loop to load the `$rows` array.

**Note**

If you have a particularly large result set that is impractical to load into memory, then you can instead use [`mysqli_data_seek`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php) to reset the data pointer before you start reading from the result set. So where you have

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res_kwal)) {
```

change it to

```
mysqli_data_seek($res_kwal, 0);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res_kwal)) {
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to iterate over each row without loading into an array? This way you don't run into problems on large result sets. I'm not seeing a LIMIT BY in the query...

Comment: @JamieBelcher as I understand OPs question he is executing the same query multiple times, which is slow. The intention of this is to fetch the data once and then read it from the array each time it is required after the first time.

Comment: @JamieBelcher I've added an alternate solution using `mysqli_data_seek` should the size of the result set be an issue. Given that it is being used to make a `select`, I think it's unlikely but it doesn't hurt to have options.

Comment: Very, very nice :)

Comment: @Muiter :-) I'm glad you like it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the code you provided here lacks the outer loop, so I'm going to work with what I have.

If that loop really slows down your page you should consider using ajax to load the content of the menu after the page has loaded, something like this:

```
<select class="form-control" id="edit_kwaliteit_id['.$i.']" name="edit_kwaliteit_id" onchange="validate_edit_table_1(this, '.$i.')">';

     // add a loader while page loads
     <div id="menu-loader"></div>
</select>
```

Fetch the menu content after page loads

```
$(window).on("load", function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/endpointForFetchingMenuContent',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {},
        success: function( response ) {
            response = JSON.parse( response );

            if(response) {
                $("#menu-loader").hide();
                $("#edit_kwaliteit_id").append(response);
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.log( xhr.responseText );
        }
    });

});
```

Php endpoint:

```
// do your query
....
// loop through the result and build your menu
ob_start();
while($row_kwal = mysqli_fetch_array($res_kwal)) {

                echo '<option ';if($row_table_1['kwaliteit_id'] == $row_kwal['id']) { echo 'selected="selected"';} echo 'value="'.$row_kwal['id'].'">'.$row_kwal['kwaliteit'].'</option>';
            }
$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

echo json_endcode($output); exit();
```